# TypeError When Creating Conda Environment

Tags: anaconda, conda

I am attempting to create a conda environment from a yaml file with the following command:

```
conda env create -f myenv.yml python=3
```

When my yaml file is written like this:

```
name: myenv
channels:
  - conda-forge
dependencies:
  - django=1.10.5
  - pip:
    - gunicorn==19.7.0
    - psycopg2==2.6.2
```

It works fine.

When my yaml file is written like this (without the conda-forge package/channel):

```
name: myenv
dependencies:
  - pip:
    - gunicorn==19.7.0
    - psycopg2==2.6.2
```

It generates the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/myuser/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/conda/exceptions.py", line 573, in conda_exception_handler
    return_value = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/myuser/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/conda_env/cli/main_create.py", line 108, in execute
    installer.install(prefix, pkg_specs, args, env)
  File "/home/myuser/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/conda_env/installers/pip.py", line 8, in install
    pip_cmd = pip_args(prefix) + ['install', ] + specs
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'list'
```

I need to use the second yaml example without the conda-forge package.

Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMO, this looks like a [bug](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/4985) in conda. However, you can get around this by adding pip as a dependency. So, make sure the file `myenv.yml` has the following contents:

```
name: myenv
dependencies:
  - pip=9.0.1=py27_1
  - pip:
    - gunicorn==19.7.0
    - psycopg2==2.6.2
```

Comment: Thanks. Works! BTW it also works without specifying py27_1. I specified python=3 in my conda create command so it installed pip=9.0.1=py36_1.

Comment: Yeah, I was testing this in a py2 base install. And yes, specifying the build string isn't necessary.